# Redux error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I saw this question has been asked a lot. But I failed to solve my issue. Forgive me for my incompetence. Trying redux first time. I am trying to do a login, logout operation.

**Store configuration:**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware)),
);

export default store;
```

**Reducer Index:**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import loginReducer from './loginReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    loginData: loginReducer,
});
```

**Login Reducer:**

```
import { ERROR_LOG, LOGIN, LOGOUT } from '@/actions/types';

const initialState = {
  token: null,
  data: null,
  error: null,
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGIN:
      return {
        ...state,
        data: action.payload,
        token:action.payload.token
      };

    case LOGOUT:
      console.log('logout',action)
      return{
        ...state,
        data:null,
      }
    case ERROR_LOG:
      return { ...state, error: action.payload };
  
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**Action:**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { ERROR_LOG, LOGIN, LOGOUT } from './types';

import common from '../models/common';

export const loginAction = (data) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.post(`${common.api}/sign-in`, data);
    const loginData = await res.data;

    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN,
      payload: loginData,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: ERROR_LOG,
      payload: error.response.data,
    });
  }
};

export const logOutAction = () =>  dispatch => {
  console.log("inside action")
  try {
    console.log("inside try")
    dispatch({
      type: LOGOUT,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("inside error")
    dispatch({
      type: ERROR_LOG,
      payload: error.response.data,
    });
  }
};
```

Types are imported from another file.

```
export const ERROR_LOG = 'ERROR_LOG';
export const LOGIN = 'LOGIN';
export const LOGOUT = 'LOGOUT';
```

So on login button I am invoking the `logicAction` which is working fine. Still providing the code:

```
  const handleSubmit = (values) => {
    loginAction(values);
  };
```

import and the react-redux connect used as docs said. Same way I tried to add logout to `logout button`.

```
onMenuClick = (event) => {
 this.props.logOutAction();
}
```

But the same thing throwing me

> Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async
> actions.

From console I can see it throws error immediately as it hits the `dispatch` . For that no `console.log` is printed.

I have absolutely no idea what is the problem here.

**EDIT:**

mapStateToProps in login component where it is working fine:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  loginData: state.loginData,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { loginAction })(Login);
```

mapStateToProps in header component:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  loginData: state.loginData,
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { logOutAction })(AvatarDropdown);
```

Basically I just copy/paste from login component.

Comment: If you get rid of `dispatch({
      type: ERROR_LOG,
      payload: error.response.data,
    });`, does the error go away? I'm wondering if `error.response.data` is not a plain object and that is why you get the error.

Comment: Nah. It wasn't there in first place. Tried it to see if anything different happens. It doesn't not even go inside there. `logOutAction = () =>  dispatch =>` throws error in this dispatch.

Comment: Are you using `mapDispatchToProps` in your React component to dispatch your action? If so, can you show that code?

Comment: Edited and included. Not `mapDispatchToProps`, used `mapStateToProps`

Comment: One differenence. In login component I used functional component. passed like this, `const Login = ({ loginData: { data, error }, loginAction }) =>`. For logout, header component is class component. Saw in doc, I should then take stuff from `props`. Logged that `props` . It does show a function. Log `{loginData: undefined, logOutAction: ƒ} `

Comment: So you don't get `inside action` or `inside try` logged to the console?

Comment: yeah. didn't get `inside action`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a framework which has built in store. So there was a conflict between stores.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the **initialState** from your store configuration. I don't think you need it and it might be the source of your error. Try to use this:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
   rootReducer,
   composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware)),
);

export default store;
```